# Eclipse Zest Visualization Toolkit VS ZestSDK

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, zest

When trying to install AntlrDT into a clean/new installation of eclipse-photon through Certiv update site I face with the following installation requirements:

**Requirements:**

- Eclipse 4.5.2 on Java 8 JDK VM
- Eclipse Zest Visualization Toolkit 1.5

**Packages installed:**

- Java version: 1.8.0
- Eclipse versión installed:Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Photon ,release (4.8.0) Build id: 20180619-1200
- Installed plugin: ZestSDK 1.7.0

Is Zest Visualization Toolkit embedded into ZestSDK, are both equivalent?

If not, how to install it, since from the menu

Help  > Install New Software

> Help  > Install New Software

there is not option to install Visualization Toolit (only ZestSDK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write down the [answer](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1804908/) obtained from Eclipse Community Forums:

*The SDK build is fine to install, that includes the runtime for the Zest Visualization Toolkit and also includes source code, etc.
In other words, the SDK build should fulfill the requirement for AntlrDT.*